# First-order definability sums of squares

Tags: field-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory

Let $K$ be a field. I am interested in when there can exist a first-order definition of the set
$$
\Sigma K^2 := \lbrace \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \mid n \in \mathbb{N}, x_1, \ldots, x_n \in K \rbrace
$$
in $K$ in the language of rings.

Clearly, if $K$ has finite [Pythagoras number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagoras_number), then $\Sigma K^2$ has an (existential) first-order definition in $K$. In fact, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there is an existential first-order formula
$$
\varphi_n(x) := \exists x_1, \ldots, x_n : x = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2
$$
uniformly defining $\Sigma K^2$ in all fields of Pythagoras number at most $n$.

Conversely, if $K$ has infinite Pythagoras number, then there can be no first-order formula uniformly defining $\Sigma K'^2$ in all fields $K'$ elementarily equivalent to $K$. This follows from the [compactness theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem). However, this does not exclude the possibility of a field $K$ with infinite Pythagoras number and such that $\Sigma K^2$ has a first-order definition in $K$ which does not carry over to fields elementarily equivalent to $K$.

So my broad question is to understand this problem better. More specifically, I would like to understand when $\Sigma K^2$ is definable in a field $K$ of infinite Pythagoras number. Any example of a field with infinite Pythagoras number where you can prove or disprove that $\Sigma K^2$ is (existentially) definable would already be very helpful.

Comment: What are the standard examples of fields of infinite Pythagoras number?

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti It follows from a result by Cassels (although I cannot find a publicly accesible reference) that for any formally real field $K$ (i.e. -1 is not a sum of squares in $K$) one has that the Pythagoras number of $K(X)$ is at least one more than that of $K$. Hence the rational function field in infinitely many variables $K(X_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N})$ has infinite Pythagoras number. If $K = \mathbb{R}$, it is known that any finitely generated subfield of $\mathbb{R}(X_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N})$ has finite Pythagoras number.